# session.js file(OOB) override Liferay 7.

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-7

I am working on migration of my project from liferay 6x to lifeary 7x. The task is to override the OOB(out of box) file session.js and customized the session warning/error message.I have overrided the Language_en.properties for text customization of error/warning which is working fine. But unable to override the session. js file for customization.The github location of session.js file is **liferay-portal/modules/apps/foundation/frontend-js/frontend-js-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/liferay/session.js**. As we know that hook features is deprecated in Lifeary 7 and also tried with jsp override but did not get success. Please help me with the steps how to override the session.js file in liferay 7 platform.

Thanks & appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 2):

little bit late but I've just resolved this problem.

All you need to do is create JAR module with bnd.bnd descriptor, config.js configuration file and your own session-custom.js

For Maven I have this project structure:

```
module-name
    |- src.main.resources.META-INF.resources.js
    |      |- config.js
    |      |- session-custom.js
    |- bnd.bnd
    |- pom.xml
```

bnd.bnd

```
Liferay-JS-Config: /META-INF/resources/js/config.js
Web-ContextPath: /session-custom
```

config.js

```
;(function() {
    console.log('Loading custom AUI modules configuration');

    var base = MODULE_PATH + '/js/';

    AUI().applyConfig(
        {
            groups: {
                mymodulesoverride: {
                    base: base,
                    combine: Liferay.AUI.getCombine(),
                    filter: Liferay.AUI.getFilterConfig(),
                    modules: {
                        'liferay-session-customized': {
                            path: 'session-custom.js',
                            condition: {
                                name: 'liferay-session-customized',
                                trigger: 'liferay-session',
                                when: 'instead'
                            },
                            requires: [
                                'aui-io-request',
                                'aui-timer',
                                'cookie',
                                'liferay-notification'
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    root: base
                }
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>

    <!-- ... -->

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Useful links:

[Overriding AUI module](https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/77090513#_19_message_77885507)

[CONFIGURING MODULES FOR LIFERAY PORTAL’S LOADERS](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/configuring-modules-for-liferay-portals-loaders)